# convert tibble to dataframe in r

Tags: r, tidyr

I used the following code to separate some data in the following format:

```
d <- tibble(input=c("John Hopkins Institute 8.4 8.6 9.2 Blue",
"Stanford : New School 9.4 5.6 9.2 Green",
"Mayor College 6.4 7.6 4.2 Red"))

d %>% extract(input,
          regex="(.+) ([.\\d]+) ([.\\d]+) ([.\\d]+) (.+)",
          into=c("College Names", "Food rating", "Critic Rating", "Student rating", "Color"))
```

when I run the code, it shows `d` as a 3*4 tibble but when I use:

```
var<-as.data.frame(d)
```

it forms a 3*1 dataframe with all columns combined into one like it was earlier. (eg: Row1 looks like this : "John Hopkins Institute 8.4 8.6 9.2 Blue")

Is there a way to convert this tibble in a proper dataframe ? (The data given here is just an example, and the real data has a lot of rows)

How it should look:

| College Names | Food rating | Critic Rating | Student rating | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Hopkins Institute | 8.4 | 8.6 | 9.2 | Blue |
| Stanford : New School | 9.4 | 5.6 | 9.2 | Green |
| Mayor College | 6.4 | 7.6 | 4.2 | Red |

Comment: You have save the output of extracted code into `d`. Try `d <- d %>% extract(...` then run `var<-as.data.frame(d)` again

Comment: An alternative, though I personally dislike it: `library(magrittr); d %<>% extract(...)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! 
Didn't think it was that simple haha

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not overwriten the d object after extracting (separating) the columns. This should work:

```
d <- tibble(input=c("John Hopkins Institute 8.4 8.6 9.2 Blue",
               "Stanford : New School 9.4 5.6 9.2 Green",
               "Mayor College 6.4 7.6 4.2 Red")) %>% 
  
  extract(input,
          regex="(.+) ([.\\d]+) ([.\\d]+) ([.\\d]+) (.+)",
          into=c("College Names", "Food rating", "Critic Rating", "Student rating", "Color")) %>% 
  
  as.data.frame
```